# Как открыть страницу в новой вкладке?

Tags: php, html

Знаю, что есть target и form target в html. Но они попросту не работают и открытие новой вкладки не осуществляется. Опять же, логинюсь через php, и соответсвенно мне нужно сохранить значения поля "id", оно сохраняется - все нормально. Но как мне перейти на следующую вкладку и там с ним уже работать не через консоль разработчика.

index.php код:

```
<div class= "popup" >
            <div class="form_box">
                <form  class="form" target="_blank">
                    <div class="block_item form_signin ">
                        <h2 >Авторизация</h2>
                        <a href = "#!"class= "close_button signin" ></a >
                        <input type = "login" name= "login" placeholder= "Логин"  >
                        <input type= "password" name= "pass" placeholder= "Пароль"  >
                        <input type="button" class= "btn_popup send_button" value="Войти" formtarget="_blank" />
                        <a href = "#!"class= "form_forgot" >Восстановить пароль</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block_item form_signup">
                        <h2 >Регистрация</h2>   
                        <a href = "#!"class= "close_button signup" ></a >
                        <input type = "login" name= "loginreg" placeholder= "Логин"  >
                        <input type= "email" name= "emailreg" placeholder= "E-mail"  >
                        <input type= "password" name= "passreg" placeholder= "Пароль"  >
                        <input type= "password" name= "passcheck" placeholder= "Подтвердите пароль" >
                        <input type="button" class= "btn_popup reg_button" value="Зарегистрироваться"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

login.php

```
<?php
$login = $_POST['login'];
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '0000', 'cars');
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Ошибка: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id,login, password FROM authorized WHERE login='$login' AND password='$pass'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        //header("Location: http://localhost/wow.html?id=$id");
        $page = "<a href='wow.php?id=".$id."'>".$id."</a></br>";
        echo $page;
    }

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: вам нужно перенаправить пользователя на другую страницу после успешной авторизации?

Comment: @MaxWatson, да, именно так.

Comment: ну вот так можно еще `header("Location: wow.php?id=$id");`

Comment: @MaxWatson, если так задавать, то объект будет не найден)

Comment: Какой еще объект не будет найден?

Comment: @u_mulder, wow.php - он как бы есть, но он его не открывает без префикса localhost
возможно как то можно передавать $page в JS и открывать через него... Но вообще идей нет как это можно сделать.

Comment: Если wow.php в корне проекта, то `Location: /wow.php`. Иначе надо структуру проекта смотреть

Comment: @u_mulder, так тоже работает, но мне б хотелось как то направлять человека на новую вкладку. В form и в кнопке стоят targe _blank и formtarget _blank соответственно. Но толку от этого никакого.

Comment: можно в js после запроса направить на новую вкладку через `window.open()`

Comment: @Meth0d, есть какойто набросок, чтобы примерно понимать?!

Comment: @Eliz наброска нет. Вы же как то отправляете запрос на сервер с клиента? После ответа с сервера, в зависимости от ответа делаете то или иное действие. Я фронтендер и на `onsubmit` всегда пишу `e.preventDefault()` и уже в самом запросе обрабатываю ошибки и делаю какие то действия.

Answer (score -1):

chrome чтобы открыть страницу в новой вкладке использует blank, можешь про него почитать, многое зависит от браузера и поисковой системы, есть некоторые настройки не позволяющие открывать страницу в новой вкладке. Например firefox и некоторые настройки хром. Скорее всего твой код работает, просто у тебя браузер препятствует нормальной работе  надеюсь помог

Comment: В том то и проблем `<form  class="form" target="_blank">` уже прописан атрибут. И в `<input type="button" class= "btn_popup send_button" value="Войти" formtarget="_blank" />`. Но они все равно ничего не делают.

Comment: многое зависит от браузера и поисковой системы, есть некоторые настройки не позволяющие открывать страницу в новой вкладке. Например firefox  и некоторые настройки хром. Скорее всего твой код работает, просто у тебя браузер препятствует нормальной работе